# Adding children: to SizedBox

Tags: flutter, sized-box

I am trying to put a TextField and an IconButton for a date picker together and have decided to use a SizedBox to do that with. I want them to be side by side.

[image]

I have used a Container with a SizedBox and will add the TextField and IconButton as children. However, when I do this I get an error on "children:". What am I doing wrong?

```
Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child:
                    SizedBox(
                    height: 50.0,
                    width: 150,
                    children: <Widget>[   <<<<<<< This is where the error is
                    TextField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      controller: contractDateController,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        trxnProvider.changecontractDate(value); //, loggedInUid);
                      },
                      decoration:
                      kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(
                          hintText: 'Contract Date', labelText: 'Contract Date'),
                    ),
                    IconButton(onPressed: () {_selectDate(context);}, icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today)),
                  ],),
                ),
```

Comment: Use a Row as a child of SizedBox and put the children into this Row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SizedBox() does not have "children" it can only take a "child", and to put both widgets side by side you can  make the child attr of SizedBox() a Row() and inside that row put the TextField and the IconButton

```
Container(
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 50.0,
        width: 150,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            TextField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              controller: contractDateController,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              onChanged: (value) {
                trxnProvider.changecontractDate(value); //, loggedInUid);
              },
              decoration: kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(
                  hintText: 'Contract Date', labelText: 'Contract Date'),
            ),
            IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  _selectDate(context);
                },
                icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
```